# Trouble accessing updated label contents

Tags: c#, wpf

edit: Solved

I have a label that gets populated with a value from a database. If the user enters this value into a textbox below, I want to change the background. The label displays the value fine on screen, but when I try to match the values in the textbox's textchanged event, it shows as null.

```
    public void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {          
        txtAnswer.Clear();
        txtAnswer.Background = Brushes.White;
        int number = r.Next(3) + 1;

        string queryEnglish = "SELECT englishVerb FROM verbTable WHERE (verbID = " + number + ")";
        string queryFrench = "SELECT frenchVerb FROM verbTable WHERE (verbID = " + number + ")";


        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\verbs.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"))
        {
            con.Open();

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryEnglish, con))
            {
                this.lblEnglishVerb.Content = (string)command.ExecuteScalar();
            }

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryFrench, con))
            {
                this.lblFrenchVerb.Content = (string)command.ExecuteScalar();
            }
        }            
    }


    public void txtAnswer_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtAnswer.Text == lblFrenchVerb.Content.ToString())
            txtAnswer.Background = Brushes.LightGreen;

        if (txtAnswer.Text == "test")          
            txtAnswer.Background = Brushes.AliceBlue;
    }
```

Comment: label is not standard winform control? What kind of control it is?

Comment: It's WPF, I added the wrong tag.

Comment: what value are you getting exactly in txtAnswer.txt and lblFrenchVerb.Content.ToString()? do a debug and check

Comment: Which is null?  The txtAnswer.Text value, or the lblFrenchVerb.Content.ToString() value?

Comment: not sure but might be you are doing lblFrenchVerb.Content.ToString() rather than this what value are you getting in lblFrenchVerb.Content?

Comment: When I checked it earlier lblFrenchVerb was showing as null which had me really confused, but now it's showing the proper word with a few extra spaces at the end, which is why it wasn't matching. Late night coding isn't for me I guess. Thanks for the help.

Comment: it works fine for me. there is something else wrong in your code

Comment: Can you answer your own question in a way that would help others? If you do, you can select yours as the correct answer. It may seem strange, but it is the preferred way of dealing with situations like this.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think so Will. The reason I asked the question was because I misread the output and was confused as to why I was getting a null value. After I read that it worked fine for Reniuz, I went back and saw the almost correct result. I just had to trim spaces from the end to get it to match in my code. I answered one of my own questions in the past, but I believe that this one should be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Textchanged will probably get triggered the moment 'nothing' is placed into the Content. So on the first txtAnswer_TextChanged you might get nothing.

Comment: That's true, the event will get fired many times while inputting - with no data, partial data, etc.